# How does one reduce parallel resistors when nodes intersect?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

My question is as follows: How does one go about finding the equivalent resistor, when you have two parallels that intersect each other?

I have the following circuit. I have reduced it to the diagram below so I can see things better. The main line in the second diagram is represented by arrows in the first. I see no way to reduce resistance R2 because R7 gets in the way, and I see no way to reduce R7 because R2 gets in the way. How does one solve this situation?

[image]

Comment: Your two diagrams are not equivalent. In the upper one, n4 and n2 are joined by a wire (meaning they are actually just one node). In your lower diagram, n4 and n2 are not connected.

Comment: I assumed that since there is no resistor along the connection between n2 and n4, n4 doesn't actually act as a node and has no impact. You could take it out of the second diagram and everything would be the same. Is this not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got basically two options for this:

- Use the [Y-$\Delta$ correspondence formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) to systematically work away at the complexity of the graph of your circuit and reduce it to a combination of resistors in series and in parallel.
- Write down the full set of [Kirchhoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) for your circuit, reduce it to a set of linear equations (in your case, about five equations or so), and then solve those equations via standard linear algebra.

In general, it isn't possible to use the formulas for resistances in series and in parallel to reduce arbitrary circuits down to their Thevenin or Norton equivalents - in the general case, you need the full power of the Kirchhoff laws.

---

Edit: It seems I jumped the gun with your particular example - the answer is valid in general, but for the circuit in your question you can indeed find an equivalent resistance using just the simple formulas. If you need a place to start, $R_6$ and $R_7$ are in parallel, and $R_3$ and $R_5$ combine in series to one in parallel with $R_4$.

Comment: If I wanted to join up the combination of R3 and R5 with R4 in parallel, that leaves two possible locations for the resistor. It would have to be between n2 and n3, or to the right of n3. Is there any rule governing what side it should be on? Again, thanks for your reply.